# I have encountered an issue with managing state updates effectively

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, state-management

#### I'm working on a React project and using functional components with hooks. I have encountered an issue with managing state updates effectively.  Let's say I have a component like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    // Here, Some logic to increment the count state
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The **`handleIncrement`** the function is supposed to update the **`count`** state when the button is clicked. However, I'm not sure about the best way to handle the state update, especially if there are multiple state variables.

What would be the most efficient and recommended way to handle state changes in React functional components? Are there any best practices to follow for managing state updates in such scenarios?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use Functional Updates: When updating state based on the previous state value, it's Generally a good practice to use the functional update form to avoid potential race conditions.

```js
const handleIncrement = () => {
  setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
};
```